# Getting sigarbt when adding NSDictionary to NSMutableArray mutating method sent to immutable object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I'm getting sigarbt in this code

```
if (![newPlayerName isEqual:@""] && !thereAreJustSpaces)
    {

        NSDictionary *player = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                newPlayerName, @"name", @"", @"email", nil];

        [self.playerNames addObject:player];//Getting sigarbt over here.
    }
```

Here is my console output

```
2013-03-26 08:44:30.683 ChooseTeams[3921:15203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1655022 0xfcdcd6 0x15fda48 0x15fd9b9 0x164eda8 0x164ecb0 0x43f9 0x1656e99 0x13314e 0x371a0e 0x1656e99 0x13314e 0x1330e6 0x1d9ade 0x1d9fa7 0x1d9266 0x1583c0 0x1585e6 0x13edc4 0x132634 0x17e8ef5 0x1629195 0x158dff2 0x158c8da 0x158bd84 0x158bc9b 0x17e77d8 0x17e788a 0x130626 0x26dd 0x2605 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

I have property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *playerNames;
```

and in viewDidLoad

```
self.playerNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: are you sure that `playerNames` is `NSMutableArray` ?

Comment: added on @MidhunMP: check in property and if you init-ed, in both the place

Comment: Show where you assign `self.playerNames` you're probably not assigning an `NSMutableArray` instance to it.

Comment: Yes 100 per cent sure it is mutablearray I have property @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *playerNames;
and in viewDidLoad self.playerNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; sea above.

Comment: Cannot be sure from your example where the context of this code exists in the call tree; put a few NSLog() executions near this code and in viewDidLoad and make sure the order is right -- just testing to make sure object is not nil

Comment: I suggest to set a break point at [self.playerNames addObject:player]; and check there that self.playerNames is really of class NSMutableArray. Maybe somewhere in your code your property playerNames is overwritten with a non-mutable array.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a mutablearray at the breakpoint.

Comment: ok I found the problem. its because I was saying self.playerNames = JSON; JSON is type id.

Comment: I did type well working code for you in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answer lies in your exception

2013-03-26 08:44:30.683 ChooseTeams[3921:15203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: **mutating method sent to immutable object**'

I think self.playerNames is **NSArray**, where it should be **NSMutableArray**.

Answer (score 0):

Your "playerNames" need to be mutable.

Example:

```
playerNames=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: See my edit above. I have that in my viewDidLoad. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The exception may not come from where you think it comes. It clearly says you are trying to add an object to an NSArray that is *not* mutable, so that is what happens. Either your suspect playerNames is not mutable, or you are not inserting into playerNames.

You should start learning about Xcode debugging. First, set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions. You will then see *exactly* where the problem happened. Next, display the value you stored into playerNames and check that it is still the same array when the problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.playerNames = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
   return self;
}
```

Something else:

```
newPlayerName = [newPlayerName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

if (![newPlayerName isEqualToString:@""])
    {

        NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initwithobjects:@"key1", @"key2",nil];
        NSArray *objects = [[NSArrayAlloc] initwithobjects:@"value1",@"value2",nil];

        NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

        [self.playerNames addObject:player];//Getting sigarbt over here.
    }
```